# Why completing an octet stabilises an atom, quantum mechanically?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, orbitals, quantum-chemistry, inert-gases

They say that Neon $Ne$ is stable because it has 10 electrons and with 10 electrons it completes its octet and completing an octet decreases the potential energy of an atom to the minimum and a system loves to remain in the lowest energy as possible.

Then I read that an electron is literally a probability wave and we can only talk about the probability of an electron present at a point at a certain time instant.

How are the two terms related? How do waves decide that when a system is going to be stable? How is potential energy related to these waves?

Comment: `electron is literally a probability wave` - wrong; electron is __associated__ with probability wave - if loosely written. Anyway, there are numerous posts on Octet rule both at Physics and as well as Chemistry.SE; did you check them?